Virtual interfaces on OpenvSwitch with STP do not work correctly
Network Scheme
Networks in my scheme:
CLI - 192.168.1.0/26
SRV - 192.168.1.64/28
MNGT - 192.168.1.80/29
I have a problem. I set up STP between sw-1 sw-2 sw-3 (sw-1 is the root switch), after which the virtual interfaces of these switches stopped pinging normally from other network devices. But the main feature is that when I launch a ping from both the switch and another device at the same time, it starts to go, and then the device is available for some more time.
I also forgot to add that all switches are Linux machines on the Alt Linux operating system and use openvswitch to configure the logic
